client disconnects when transferring larger files
[This is mostly a cross-post from Rasp Pi Forum. To be self-contained, let me also include the descriptions.]
My setup:

Ubuntu 22.04 [Also tried on Ubuntu 24.04, same thing happens]
Rasp Pi 4B
I have an additional wifi dongle plugged into the USB
The additional wifi dongle is responsible for connecting to the outside internet
The built-in interface is in AP mode and is responsible for a few iot devices to connect to it.

Netplan config looks like this:
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  wifis:
    # wlan0 being the pi built-in wifi
    # will use as AP mode
    wlan0:
      access-points:
        "base-AP":
          password: "12345678"
          mode: ap
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      # The pi will have ip 192.168.1.10
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.10/24
    wlan1:
      match:
        # macaddress of my usb wifi adapter
        macaddress: "24:xxxxxx:75"
      access-points:
        # the credentials for the wifi network for internet
        SomeWifiNetwork:
          password: da9ba45aa8d........87a305
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true

Now, this setup works most of the time, but from time to time, it seems like when the Pi tries to fetch some larger files from the iot devices, the device would disconnect. I am not sure about the cause of the disconnects.. This is what I see in the log when this happens:
Jul  8 14:17:47 pi-host wpa_supplicant[680]: wlan0: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED 00:d0:ca:00:40:b8
Jul  8 14:17:51 pi-host wpa_supplicant[680]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jul  8 14:17:51 pi-host wpa_supplicant[680]: wlan0: AP-STA-CONNECTED 00:d0:ca:00:40:b8
Jul  8 14:17:51 pi-host wpa_supplicant[680]: wlan0: EAPOL-4WAY-HS-COMPLETED 00:d0:ca:00:40:b8
Jul  8 14:17:51 pi-host dnsmasq-dhcp[1013]: DHCPDISCOVER(wlan0) 00:d0:ca:00:40:b8
Jul  8 14:17:51 pi-host dnsmasq-dhcp[1013]: DHCPOFFER(wlan0) 192.168.1.217 00:d0:ca:00:40:b8
Jul  8 14:17:51 pi-host dnsmasq-dhcp[1013]: DHCPREQUEST(wlan0) 192.168.1.217 00:d0:ca:00:40:b8
Jul  8 14:17:51 pi-host dnsmasq-dhcp[1013]: DHCPACK(wlan0) 192.168.1.217 00:d0:ca:00:40:b8

And this is some relevant log when I enable -dd for wpa_supplicant:
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Event message available
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Ignored event 20 (NL80211_CMD_DEL_STATION) for foreign interface (ifindex 3 wdev 0x0)
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Ignored event 20 (NL80211_CMD_DEL_STATION) for foreign interface (ifindex 3 wdev 0x0)
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Drv Event 20 (NL80211_CMD_DEL_STATION) received for wlan0
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Delete station xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wlan0: Event DISASSOC (1) received
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wlan0: Disassociation notification
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wlan0:  * reason 0 (UNKNOWN)
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wlan0:  * address xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: Disassociation frame IE(s) - hexdump(len=0): [NULL]
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: hostapd_logger: STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx - disassociated
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: dbus: Station MAC address 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx' 'StaDeauthorized'
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: dbus: Unregister STA object '/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/Stations/00d0ca003f0c'
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: dbus: STA signal StationRemoved
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wlan0: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Set STA flags - ifname=wlan0 addr=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx total_flags=0x0 flags_or=0x0 flags_and=0xfffffff1 authorized=0
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: hostapd_logger: STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx - event 2 notification
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=0xaaab0183fc40 key_idx=0 set_tx=1 seq_len=0 key_len=0 key_flag=0x20
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: DEL_KEY
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]:    addr=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]:    pairwise key
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx WPA_PTK entering state DISCONNECTED
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx WPA_PTK entering state INITIALIZE
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=0xaaab0183fc40 key_idx=0 set_tx=1 seq_len=0 key_len=0 key_flag=0x20
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: DEL_KEY
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]:    addr=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]:    pairwise key
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: set_key failed; err=-22 Invalid argument
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: RSN: PTK removal from the driver failed
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Set STA flags - ifname=wlan0 addr=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx total_flags=0x0 flags_or=0x0 flags_and=0xfffffffe authorized=0
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: hostapd_logger: STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx - unauthorizing port
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Set STA flags - ifname=wlan0 addr=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx total_flags=0x0 flags_or=0x0 flags_and=0xfffffff1 authorized=0
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: sta_remove -> DEL_STATION wlan0 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx --> 0 (Success)
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: P2P: Last non-P2P device disconnected
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: hostapd_ht_operation_update current operation mode=0x0
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: hostapd_ht_operation_update new operation mode=0x0 changes=0
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: ap_free_sta: cancel ap_handle_timer for xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Event message available
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Ignored event 20 (NL80211_CMD_DEL_STATION) for foreign interface (ifindex 3 wdev 0x0)
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Ignored event 20 (NL80211_CMD_DEL_STATION) for foreign interface (ifindex 3 wdev 0x0)
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Drv Event 20 (NL80211_CMD_DEL_STATION) received for wlan0
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Delete station xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wlan0: Event DISASSOC (1) received
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wlan0: Disassociation notification
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wlan0:  * reason 0 (UNKNOWN)
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wlan0:  * address xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: Disassociation frame IE(s) - hexdump(len=0): [NULL]
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: hostapd_logger: STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx - disassociated
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: Disassociation notification for unknown STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: dbus: flush_object_timeout_handler: Timeout - sending changed properties of object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Event message available
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Ignored event 20 (NL80211_CMD_DEL_STATION) for foreign interface (ifindex 3 wdev 0x0)
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Ignored event 20 (NL80211_CMD_DEL_STATION) for foreign interface (ifindex 3 wdev 0x0)
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Drv Event 20 (NL80211_CMD_DEL_STATION) received for wlan0
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Delete station xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wlan0: Event DISASSOC (1) received
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wlan0: Disassociation notification
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wlan0:  * reason 0 (UNKNOWN)
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wlan0:  * address xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: Disassociation frame IE(s) - hexdump(len=0): [NULL]
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: hostapd_logger: STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx - disassociated
Jul 18 21:47:01 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: Disassociation notification for unknown STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Event message available
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Ignored event 19 (NL80211_CMD_NEW_STATION) for foreign interface (ifindex 3 wdev 0x0)
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Ignored event 19 (NL80211_CMD_NEW_STATION) for foreign interface (ifindex 3 wdev 0x0)
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Drv Event 19 (NL80211_CMD_NEW_STATION) received for wlan0
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: New station xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Assoc Req IEs - hexdump(len=110): 00 11 6d 69 73 74 79 2d 62 61 73 65 2d 34 30 33 34 32 32 01 08 82 84 8b 96 24 30 48 6c 32 04 0c 12 18 60 21 02 08 1e 46 05 73 00 91 00 04 dd 16 00 50 f2 01 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 04 01 00 00 50 f2 02 2d 1a ad 01 1f ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 dd 07 00 50 f2 02 00 01 00 7f 01 04
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wlan0: Event ASSOC (0) received
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: hostapd_logger: STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx - associated
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: STA included WPA IE in (Re)AssocReq
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]:   New STA
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: ap_sta_add: register ap_handle_timer timeout for xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (300 seconds - ap_max_inactivity)
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Set STA flags - ifname=wlan0 addr=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx total_flags=0x60 flags_or=0x0 flags_and=0xfffffff1 authorized=0
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: hostapd_logger: STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx - event 1 notification
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=0xaaab018326e0 key_idx=0 set_tx=1 seq_len=0 key_len=0 key_flag=0x20
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: DEL_KEY
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]:    addr=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]:    pairwise key
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: set_key failed; err=-22 Invalid argument
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: RSN: PTK removal from the driver failed
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: P2P: First non-P2P device connected
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: IEEE 802.1X: Ignore STA - 802.1X not enabled or forced for WPS
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: hostapd_logger: STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx - start authentication
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx WPA_PTK entering state INITIALIZE
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=0xaaab018326e0 key_idx=0 set_tx=1 seq_len=0 key_len=0 key_flag=0x20
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: DEL_KEY
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]:    addr=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]:    pairwise key
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: set_key failed; err=-22 Invalid argument
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: RSN: PTK removal from the driver failed
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Set STA flags - ifname=wlan0 addr=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx total_flags=0x60 flags_or=0x0 flags_and=0xfffffffe authorized=0
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: hostapd_logger: STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx - unauthorizing port
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx WPA_PTK_GROUP entering state IDLE
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx WPA_PTK entering state AUTHENTICATION
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx WPA_PTK entering state AUTHENTICATION2
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: Get randomness: len=32 entropy=2
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Assign ANonce - hexdump(len=32): d3 6e d1 b0 3d 02 54 23 bc 30 1b a2 ff a4 79 7a 84 37 ae 42 01 c0 55 11 88 d2 3f 55 2e 85 f2 84
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx WPA_PTK entering state INITPSK
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: Searching a PSK for xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx prev_psk=(nil)
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: Searching a PSK for xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx prev_psk=(nil)
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx WPA_PTK entering state PTKSTART
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: hostapd_logger: STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx - sending 1/4 msg of 4-Way Handshake
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Send EAPOL(version=2 secure=0 mic=0 ack=1 install=0 pairwise=1 kde_len=0 keyidx=0 encr=0)
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Replay Counter - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Use EAPOL-Key timeout of 1000 ms (retry counter 1)
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wlan0: hostapd_new_assoc_sta: reschedule ap_handle_timer timeout for xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (300 seconds - ap_max_inactivity)
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: l2_packet_receive: src=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx len=123
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wlan0: RX EAPOL from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: RX EAPOL - hexdump(len=123): 01 03 00 77 fe 01 0a 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 ea 97 b1 95 cb d6 87 a5 f3 12 ef f2 81 43 c6 ac 7b 5b 08 b5 99 7c ec 9f 58 42 bf c3 97 73 4b 2b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 17 75 1c cd fd 3e 95 f1 cf ca 60 2b 5a cf 32 01 00 18 dd 16 00 50 f2 01 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 04 01 00 00 50 f2 02
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: IEEE 802.1X: 123 bytes from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]:    IEEE 802.1X: version=1 type=3 length=119
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: RX EAPOL data - hexdump(len=123): 01 03 00 77 fe 01 0a 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 ea 97 b1 95 cb d6 87 a5 f3 12 ef f2 81 43 c6 ac 7b 5b 08 b5 99 7c ec 9f 58 42 bf c3 97 73 4b 2b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 17 75 1c cd fd 3e 95 f1 cf ca 60 2b 5a cf 32 01 00 18 dd 16 00 50 f2 01 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 04 01 00 00 50 f2 02
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Received EAPOL-Key from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx key_info=0x10a type=254 mic_len=16 key_data_length=24
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: EAPOL-Key header (ending before Key MIC) - hexdump(len=77): fe 01 0a 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 ea 97 b1 95 cb d6 87 a5 f3 12 ef f2 81 43 c6 ac 7b 5b 08 b5 99 7c ec 9f 58 42 bf c3 97 73 4b 2b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: EAPOL-Key Key MIC - hexdump(len=16): 17 75 1c cd fd 3e 95 f1 cf ca 60 2b 5a cf 32 01
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Received Key Nonce - hexdump(len=32): ea 97 b1 95 cb d6 87 a5 f3 12 ef f2 81 43 c6 ac 7b 5b 08 b5 99 7c ec 9f 58 42 bf c3 97 73 4b 2b
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Received Replay Counter - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01
Jul 18 21:47:04 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: hostapd_logger: STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx - received EAPOL-Key frame (2/4 Pairwise)
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx WPA_PTK entering state PTKCALCNEGOTIATING
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: Searching a PSK for xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx prev_psk=(nil)
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: PTK derivation using PRF(SHA1)
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: PTK derivation - A1=dc:a6:32:73:0f:d5 A2=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Nonce1 - hexdump(len=32): d3 6e d1 b0 3d 02 54 23 bc 30 1b a2 ff a4 79 7a 84 37 ae 42 01 c0 55 11 88 d2 3f 55 2e 85 f2 84
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Nonce2 - hexdump(len=32): ea 97 b1 95 cb d6 87 a5 f3 12 ef f2 81 43 c6 ac 7b 5b 08 b5 99 7c ec 9f 58 42 bf c3 97 73 4b 2b
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: PMK - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: PTK - hexdump(len=48): [REMOVED]
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: KCK - hexdump(len=16): [REMOVED]
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: KEK - hexdump(len=16): [REMOVED]
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: TK - hexdump(len=16): [REMOVED]
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: EAPOL-Key MIC using HMAC-SHA1
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: WPA IE in EAPOL-Key - hexdump(len=24): dd 16 00 50 f2 01 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 04 01 00 00 50 f2 02
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx WPA_PTK entering state PTKCALCNEGOTIATING2
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx WPA_PTK entering state PTKINITNEGOTIATING
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: hostapd_logger: STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx - sending 3/4 msg of 4-Way Handshake
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Send EAPOL(version=2 secure=0 mic=1 ack=1 install=1 pairwise=1 kde_len=28 keyidx=0 encr=0)
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Replay Counter - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: EAPOL-Key MIC using HMAC-SHA1
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Use EAPOL-Key timeout of 1000 ms (retry counter 1)
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: l2_packet_receive: src=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx len=99
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wlan0: RX EAPOL from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: RX EAPOL - hexdump(len=99): 01 03 00 5f fe 01 0a 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ab 58 14 2f 9a 9e 12 06 18 c7 9c c2 7f f8 65 dd 00 00
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: IEEE 802.1X: 99 bytes from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]:    IEEE 802.1X: version=1 type=3 length=95
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: RX EAPOL data - hexdump(len=99): 01 03 00 5f fe 01 0a 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ab 58 14 2f 9a 9e 12 06 18 c7 9c c2 7f f8 65 dd 00 00
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Received EAPOL-Key from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx key_info=0x10a type=254 mic_len=16 key_data_length=0
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: EAPOL-Key header (ending before Key MIC) - hexdump(len=77): fe 01 0a 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: EAPOL-Key Key MIC - hexdump(len=16): ab 58 14 2f 9a 9e 12 06 18 c7 9c c2 7f f8 65 dd
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Received Key Nonce - hexdump(len=32): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Received Replay Counter - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: hostapd_logger: STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx - received EAPOL-Key frame (4/4 Pairwise)
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: EAPOL-Key MIC using HMAC-SHA1
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx WPA_PTK entering state PTKINITDONE
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=3 addr=0xaaab018326e0 key_idx=0 set_tx=1 seq_len=0 key_len=16 key_flag=0x2c
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: NEW_KEY
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: KEY_DATA - hexdump(len=16): [REMOVED]
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]:    addr=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]:    pairwise key
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: dbus: Register STA object '/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/Stations/00d0ca003f0c'
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: dbus: STA signal StationAdded
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: dbus: Station MAC address 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx' 'StaAuthorized'
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wlan0: AP-STA-CONNECTED xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: nl80211: Set STA flags - ifname=wlan0 addr=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx total_flags=0x61 flags_or=0x1 flags_and=0xffffffff authorized=1
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: hostapd_logger: STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx - authorizing port
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: hostapd_logger: STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx - pairwise key handshake completed (WPA)
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wlan0: EAPOL-4WAY-HS-COMPLETED xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx WPA_PTK_GROUP entering state REKEYNEGOTIATING
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: hostapd_logger: STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx - sending 1/2 msg of Group Key Handshake
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Send EAPOL(version=2 secure=1 mic=1 ack=1 install=0 pairwise=0 kde_len=32 keyidx=1 encr=1)
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Replay Counter - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: Plaintext EAPOL-Key Key Data - hexdump(len=40): [REMOVED]
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Encrypt Key Data using AES-WRAP (KEK length 16)
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: EAPOL-Key MIC using HMAC-SHA1
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Use EAPOL-Key timeout of 1000 ms (retry counter 1)
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: dbus: flush_object_timeout_handler: Timeout - sending changed properties of object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: l2_packet_receive: src=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx len=99
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: wlan0: RX EAPOL from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: RX EAPOL - hexdump(len=99): 01 03 00 5f fe 03 12 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 25 4f 53 ec be 42 21 4f 39 fd cc 7b ea 92 71 44 00 00
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: IEEE 802.1X: 99 bytes from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]:    IEEE 802.1X: version=1 type=3 length=95
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: RX EAPOL data - hexdump(len=99): 01 03 00 5f fe 03 12 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 25 4f 53 ec be 42 21 4f 39 fd cc 7b ea 92 71 44 00 00
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Received EAPOL-Key from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx key_info=0x312 type=254 mic_len=16 key_data_length=0
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: EAPOL-Key header (ending before Key MIC) - hexdump(len=77): fe 03 12 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: EAPOL-Key Key MIC - hexdump(len=16): 25 4f 53 ec be 42 21 4f 39 fd cc 7b ea 92 71 44
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Received Key Nonce - hexdump(len=32): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: Received Replay Counter - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: hostapd_logger: STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx - received EAPOL-Key frame (2/2 Group)
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: EAPOL-Key MIC using HMAC-SHA1
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx WPA_PTK_GROUP entering state REKEYESTABLISHED
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: hostapd_logger: STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx - group key handshake completed (WPA)
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi wpa_supplicant[351221]: WPA: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx WPA_PTK_GROUP entering state IDLE
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi dnsmasq-dhcp[351237]: DHCPDISCOVER(wlan0) xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi dnsmasq-dhcp[351237]: DHCPOFFER(wlan0) 192.168.1.54 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi dnsmasq-dhcp[351237]: DHCPREQUEST(wlan0) 192.168.1.54 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
Jul 18 21:47:05 pi dnsmasq-dhcp[351237]: DHCPACK(wlan0) 192.168.1.54 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 

So it does reconnect back, but this brief disconnect (sometimes multiple instances in a short period of time, potentially caused by my retry logic for the large file fetching) causes me a lot of issues, so I'm trying to figure out what exactly is causing the disconnects and what are the potential solutions. In order to further diagnose the issue, I also tried circumventing the Pi as an AP altogether, and route the communications to go through my main home router. So far, it seems that when I do that, the iot devices do not disconnect from my main router. This leads me to believe something is acting up with my pi's built-in wifi, causing the disconnects to happen when the client tries to transfer large files. I am not 100% certain on that though. I also tried on another pi board, and got the same behavior..
So, I'm open to:

Pointers on how to further pinpoint the root cause of the issue;
Pointers on how to resolve this issue.

Thank you!

Do NOT obfuscate logs. How can we tell if xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx differs from xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx?

@waltinator I saw others do it while searching the site, so followed suit. But yeah, I can add clarification that they are all the same. I would have used different placeholders if they were not.

The disconnect seems to come from the IOT device. How are your power supplies?

By obfuscating the MAC address, you prevent us (the experts you're consulting) from knowing the manufacturer of the NIC, and it's characteristics.  What are you trying to conceal? If you change a log file, I can no longer trust the log. What other changes did you make? Did you  add, delete, alter or reorder entries? Did you make any accidental changes? How can I be sure?

@waltinator The confusing thing is if I leave wlan1 as is, but instead of using wlan0 as an AP for (Pi:wlan0 <-> iot), route things through a standalone router (Pi:wlan0 - router - iot), then things seem to be stable, which leads me to think it's something about the pi as an AP setup. But I tried a different pi board, and also tried a fresh SD card with ubuntu 24.04 (instead of the original 22.04), but still got the same issue with the AP mode.
